# Teste de promisses em aplicação AngulaJS usando Karma e Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testes-de-unidade, assincronismo, jasmine

Olá,

Estou com uma aplicação em AngularJS e eu quis garantir a qualidade do meu código fazendo testes unitários e estou usando Karma e Jasmine pra isso. Depois de ter tido uma certa dificuldade para configurar as injeções de dependências e etc consegui finalmente "acessar" as funções da minha controller e realizar os testes. porém estou com dificuldades de fazer os testes das promisses , não estou conseguindo encontrar como faço pra simular o retorno da chamada assincrona para poder seguir com o teste da minha função.

será que alguém saberia como me dar ajudar?

Este é o meu Service:

```
angular.module('projetoServices', [])
.factory('projetoService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
        consultaLink: function (entrada) {
            return $http.post('http://localhost:7001', entrada})
                .then(tratarResposta, tratarErro);
        },
    };

    function tratarResposta(response) {
        if (response.data.data == null) {
            return response.data;
        } else {
            return response.data.data;
        }
    }

    function tratarErro(error) {
        if (error.data.data == null) {
            return error.data;
        } else {
            return error.data.data;
        }
    }

}]);
```

Segue função dentro da minha controller que quero testar:

```
vm = this;
vm.abreLink = abreLink;

function abreLink(id) {
        projetoService.consultaLink({ "id": id}).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                   var html = response.url;
        $window.open(html, '_Blank',);
            }
        });
}
```

Dentro da minha classe de teste estou injetando meu service através do arquivo moduleCommonsInit

```
(function (angular) {

angular.mock.moduleCommonsInit = function () {

    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('projetoService', function ($q) {
            return {
                    consultaLink: function () {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    defer.resolve({ id: 1, url: www.alura.com.br });
                    return defer.promise;
                },
            };
        });

    });
};
}(angular));
```

e este é o meu teste:

```
describe('testes da projeto
Controller', function () {
var $rootScope, $scope, $q, $httpBackend, $controller, vm;

beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.moduleCommonsInit();
    angular.mock.module('projeto
Controllers');
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_,_$httpBackend_, projetoService) {

    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    vm = _$controller_('projetoController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        projetoService : projetoService
    });

}));

it('Teste AbreLink()...', function () {
    var id = "1";

    vm.abreLink(id);

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Coisas que vejo faltarem:

- os testes têm de saber quando estão completos

Quando tens `it('Teste AbreLink()...', function () {`, e uma vez que estás a fazer testes assíncronos, tens de retornar uma Promise ou usar o argumento dessa função. Sugiro usares `it('Teste AbreLink()...', function (done) {` e depois chamares essa função `done` que te é passada nos argumentos para terminar o teste.

- a função testada não dá indicação que tenha sido completada

Quando usas `abreLink(id)` essa função não dá para testar... ou seja, não é possível saber quando ela de facto abre outra janela. Sugiro adicionar um argumento a essa função que corra quando a janela carregar. Por exemplo: `abreLink(id, cb)` e a função ser definida assim:

```
function abreLink(id, cb) {
    projetoService.consultaLink({ "id": id}).then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
           var html = response.url;
           var win = $window.open(html, '_Blank');
           win.addEventListener('load', cb);
        }
    });
}
```

#### Assim podes correr o teste desta maneira:

```
it('Teste AbreLink()...', function (done) {
    var id = "1";
    vm.abreLink(id, done);
});
```

Comment: Olá Sergio, 

Primeiramente obrigado pela sugestão.

Tentei fazer a alteração sugerida, executei o meu teste mas ainda assim o relatorio do coverage só aparece como coberta por teste até o trecho "projetoService.consultaLink({ "codigoConfiguracaoConteudoInteracao": codigoLink }).then" e não percorre nada da função de callback que segue esse .then

obrigado pela ajuda, porém meu problema ainda persiste.